# ¿Porque PHPmyAdmin no acepta esta condicion IF dentro de una funcion?

Tags: mysql, funciones, phpmyadmin, condiciones

Estoy haciendo una función en MySQL sin embargo cuando intento grabarla no me lo permite y  el error sale dentro  del siguiente IF.

```
   /* Verifica que el empleado esté excento */
       IF SELECT Count(*) FROM ExcentosDedApo 
        WHERE(CvePersonal=CvePersonal)AND(Clave=CveDedApo)>0
        THEN
        RETURN 0;
        END IF;
```

El mensaje de error que sale es

```
MySQL ha dicho: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'SELECT Count(*) FROM ExcentosDedApo WHERE(CvePersonal=CvePersonal)AND(Clave=C...' en la linea 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré el error
Lo coloco por si alguien lo llega a necesitar en alguna ocasión, el problema eran los paréntesis

```
/* Verifica que el empleado esté excento */  
IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM ExcentosDedApo WHERE(CvePersonal=CvePersonal)AND(Clave=CveDedApo))>0
THEN
RETURN 0;
END IF;
```